# Add separator icon to quick launch panel

Tags: icons, panel, launcher

I would like to split categories of icons on my quick launch panel with separator.

Can't find it on Panel properties or just add it.

How can I do this?

Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a separator right click on your panel and select *Add to Panel...*. There you can choose a separator from a list of items:

[image]